# Existing List of W3C compliant html attribute

Tags: html, w3c

Is there a place I can see which attribute are w3c on all HTML Element, div, p, a, li, hr, etc. ...

I checked on w3cshool, but found nothing.

I need a list where they said something like ... id : (div, a , hr , etc ...), class (div, a , hr , etc) ...

Comment: do you want HTML4, XHTML or HTML5? Also, just because a tag is in the spec doesn't mean you should use it (ie not all HTML5 tags are supported in all browsers yet)

Comment: @Sudley i need for XHTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely, the [HTML specification (index of attributes)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/attributes.html) itself is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Just complementing the previous answer from Bruno. Follow HTML5 current working draft.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the list of html4 elements on the w3c site: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html

You might also want the html5 version: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#index-of-elements
It also has a nice html4/html5 comparison.